# PHP - imagecopyresampled: cut off x pixels from bottom of image

Tags: php

I need to cut off 20 pixels from the bottom.

This is what I've tried:

```
    if($mime == 'image/png'){
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($entry);
    }else{
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($entry);   
    }


    $dst_x = 0; 
    $dst_y = 0;
    $src_x = 0;
    $src_y = 0;
    $new_width = $width; 
    $new_height = $height - 20;

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($image_p, 'crop.jpg', 100);
```

I get the same image but just resized in height by -20px and without bottom cut off, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm using this beautiful alternative to that idiotic bs above:

```
$im2 = imagecrop($image, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $new_height]);

imagejpeg($im2, 'crop.jpg', 100);
```